# Imported HTML menu won't drop down Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

If I use the navbar HTML code directly on the page, all works well. If I import the navbar, when I resize the page, the dropdown menu botton doesn't do anything.

```
<head>
   <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script> 
        $(function(){
         $("#headerID").load("partials/_navbar.html"); 
          $("#footerID").load("partials/_footer.html"); 
        });
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-scroller">
      <div class="main-panel">
        
        <header id="header">
        <div id="headerID"></div>
        </header>

     </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

There is more in the head, but like I said, if I replace `<div id="headerID"></div>` with the HTML code from _navbar.html all works well. The problem occurs when I import the HTML code.

Comment: "... won't drop down Bootstrap" is a nonsensical phrase. If you added "Bootstrap" as a tag in your title, please don't. Also, please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Please show the contents of the HTML files. Since you're asking about that, we need to see it.